# ExternalSignature itext problems

Tags: java, digital-signature, itext7

I am developing a program to sign PDF documents with PKCS11 using the IExternalSignature interface that I found in some tutorials, this is the main code in addition to the implemented interface:

```
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.StampingProperties;
import com.itextpdf.signatures.BouncyCastleDigest;
import com.itextpdf.signatures.IExternalDigest;
import com.itextpdf.signatures.IExternalSignature;
import com.itextpdf.signatures.PdfSignatureAppearance;
import com.itextpdf.signatures.PdfSigner;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;

public class Sign {
    public static void signRemote(String certificate, String password,
        String token, String module, Long slot,
        String reason, String location, String contact,
        String input, String output
    ) throws CertificateException, FileNotFoundException, IOException,
        KeyStoreException, GeneralSecurityException {
        CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        Certificate[] chain = new Certificate[3];
        int i = 0;

        for(Certificate cert : factory.generateCertificates(
            new FileInputStream(certificate))
        ) {
            chain[i] = cert;
            i++;
        }

        PdfReader reader;
        
        reader = new PdfReader(input);
        PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(
            reader,
            new FileOutputStream(output),
            new StampingProperties()
        );
        signer.setCertificationLevel(PdfSigner.CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED);

        PdfSignatureAppearance sap = signer.getSignatureAppearance();
        sap
            .setReason(reason)
            .setLocation(location)
            .setContact(contact);
        signer.setFieldName("signature");

        IExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
        IExternalSignature signature = new PKCS11Signature(
            password, token, module, slot
        );

        signer.signDetached(
            digest, signature, chain,
            null, null, null,
            0, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS
        );

        reader.close();        
    }
```

```
import com.itextpdf.signatures.DigestAlgorithms;
import com.itextpdf.signatures.IExternalSignature;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11;

public class PKCS11Signature implements IExternalSignature {
    private final String password;
    private final String token;
    private final String module;
    private final Long slot;

    public PKCS11Signature(
        String password, String token, String module, Long slot
    ) {
        this.password = password;
        this.token = token;
        this.module = module;
        this.slot = slot;
    }

    @Override
    public String getHashAlgorithm() {
        return DigestAlgorithms.SHA256;
    }

    @Override
    public String getEncryptionAlgorithm() {
        return "RSA";
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] sign(byte[] message) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        try {
            BouncyCastleProvider providerBC = new BouncyCastleProvider();
            Security.addProvider(providerBC);

            String config =
                "name = " + this.token + "\n" +
                "library = " + this.module + "\n" +
                "slot = " + this.slot;
            ByteArrayInputStream bais =
                new ByteArrayInputStream(config.getBytes());
            SunPKCS11 providerPKCS11 = new SunPKCS11(bais);
            Security.addProvider(providerPKCS11);

            // Load your private key from the key store
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", providerPKCS11);
            ks.load(null, this.password.toCharArray());

            // load key or chain
            String alias = ks.aliases().nextElement();
            PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey)ks.getKey(alias, null);

            // Sign the hash received from the server
            Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
            sig.initSign(pk);
            sig.update(message);

            return sig.sign();
        } catch (IOException |
            NoSuchAlgorithmException |
            CertificateException ex
        ) {
            Logger.getLogger(Signature.class.getName()
            ).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

The exception I have is the following:

```
com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: Unknown PdfException.
    at com.itextpdf.signatures.PdfPKCS7.getEncodedPKCS7(PdfPKCS7.java:934)
    at com.itextpdf.signatures.PdfSigner.signDetached(PdfSigner.java:648)
    at com.itextpdf.signatures.PdfSigner.signDetached(PdfSigner.java:538)
    at pdf.pkcs11.Sign.signRemote(Sign.java:60)
    at pdf.pkcs11.SignTest.testSignRemote(SignTest.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.itextpdf.signatures.PdfPKCS7.getEncodedPKCS7(PdfPKCS7.java:857)
    ... 33 more
```

I don't have much experience with PDF specification, so any guidelines are welcome to correct my program.

Comment: `com.itextpdf.signatures.PdfPKCS7.getEncodedPKCS7(PdfPKCS7.java:857)` is where the certificates from the chain are parsed. Is there possibly a `null` value in your `Certificate[] chain`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion.
I checked each element of the certificate chain and you are correct. Assign an array of three but only one certificate existed. Modify the file so that it contains the three certificates in the chain and the code ran without errors.

Thanks a lot.